# How do I find multuple IDs that contain a specific word using Playwright in python?

Tags: python, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

I'm trying to learn the Python version of Playwright,

How do I locate multiple elements partially by their ID, and then proceed to click on them?
For example,
the first element in the page has the ID of "id="railRadio_420"", the second one has "id="railRadio_421"", the third one has "id="railRadio_422"", etc...., the last element has the ID of id="railRadio_424"

The IDs are sequential as seen above, but there are 2 issues.

- The first issue is that the first element has a random starting number each time so we don't know what are the three digits -> id="railRadio_XXX"
- The second issue is that we don't know how many IDs there are in the first place, so for example the sequence could be from ID number 421 to 424 or 421 to 426,

Is there a way where I can find how many IDs there are and what the ID numbers are so I can click on each one of them?

I tried to make a loop that clicks through all the IDs

```
    startingNumber = 432
    for i in range(5):
        railRadio_X = 'railRadio_' + str(startingNumber)
        page.click('[id='+ railRadio_X +']')
        train_nmb +=1
```

The issue is that I don't know what the starting number is and don't know how many IDs there are.
Any ideas how can I locate the IDs by checking if they contain the text "railRadio_" using Playwright?

Comment: If you share the actual page and your expected result, there may be a [better way to achieve your goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) than this. Usually there's more than one way to select things. That said, there's the `[id^="railRadio_"]` prefixed attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop, do this:

```
all = page.query_selector_all('*[id*="railRadio"]')
        for item in all:
            item.click()
```

When you use Asterisk (*) it means that you are searching for a partial match. All the IDs that contain the phrase "railRadio" will be found. You will be able to iterate over them and click each one.